# Swagger express structure

Tags: json, express, structure, swagger

Ideally, I want to create a Swagger 2.0 express as follow:

```
{
 "AccessPolicy": {
    "ActionList": {
      "Action": [
        "ViewFrom",
        "StreamTo",
        "Playback",
        "Record",
        "PVR",
        "Get",
        "Modify",
        "Delete",
        "Start"
      ]          
    }   
  }
}
```

in order to be a paragraph of valid JSON, I wrote as below

```
"models":{
    "Action": {
                    "id": "Action",
                    "description": "Action",
                    "required": [
                        "ViewFrom",
                        "StreamTo",
                        "Playback",
                        "Record",
                        "PVR",
                        "Get",
                        "Modify",
                        "Delete",
                        "Start"
                    ],
                    "properties": {                     
                            "ViewFrom": {"type": "string"},
                            "StreamTo": {"type": "string"},
                            "Playback": {"type": "string"},
                            "Record":{"type": "string"},
                            "PVR":{"type": "string"},
                            "Get": {"type": "string"},
                            "Modify":{"type": "string"},
                            "Delete": {"type": "string"},
                            "Start": {"type": "string"}                     
                    }
                }
}
```

shows me a different structure like this:

```
{
  "AccessPolicy": {        
    "ActionList": {
      "Action": {
        "ViewFrom": "",
        "StreamTo": "",
        "Playback": "",
        "Record": "",
        "PVR": "",
        "Get": "",
        "Modify": "",
        "Delete": "",
        "Start": ""
      }            
    }
  }
}
```

Is that possible to create the ideal structure with a **list(or enum?)** of actions (ViewFrom, StreamTo,...) without the`:"",` parts after them? 
 (I don't care, as long as I can get the square bracket [] instead of the curly braces{} after Action (4th line in ideal structure).. )

Not sure if I expressed my idea clearly..but hopefully you could understand...

Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details if possible, ie: is this a definition? Is `[ "ViewFrom", ..." ]` an enumaeration of possible options for `Action`?

Comment: If you can clarify the requirement a bit better, I should be able to give you a definition that works. Am I correct to assume that `Action` is an array of a predefined values (0 or more out of the given list)?

Comment: `Action` is either an array or enum (not sure about the difference) with several actions (ViewFrom, StreamTo, Playback, etc...). I just want to get a structure of "Action": ["ViewFrom",
        "StreamTo",
        "Playback",
        "Record",
        "PVR",
        "Get",
        "Modify",
        "Delete",
        "Start"
      ] rather than "Action": {"ViewFrom": "","StreamTo": "","Playback": "","Record": "","PVR": "","Get": "","Modify": "","Delete": "","Start": ""} . I don't know whether that makes sense to you, and sorry if not. I am just not an engieener but assigned to do documents...